# Ruby print function

Tags: ruby

```
# Call the each method of each collection in turn.
# This is not a parallel iteration and does not require enumerators.
def sequence(*enumerables, &block)
    enumerables.each do |enumerable|
        enumerable.each(&block)
    end
end


# Examples of how these iterator methods work
a,b,c = [1,2,3],4..6,'a'..'e'
print "#{sequence(a,b,c) {|x| print x}}\n"
```

why the results is:

```
123456abcde[[1, 2, 3], 4..6, "a".."e"]
```

anyone could tell me why [[1, 2, 3], 4..6, "a".."e"] is getting printed?
or tell me why the return value of the 'sequence' method is [[1, 2, 3], 4..6, "a".."e"]??
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sequence(a,b,c) { |x| print x }
```

prints `123456abcde` and

```
print "#{some_code}\n"
```

will print the return value of `some_code`. In your example the `each` loops returns `[[1, 2, 3], 4..6, "a".."e"]`, because the return value if `each` is `self` (see: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Enumerator/each)